# Ionic android app crashes when playing local videos

Tags: android, ionic-framework, html5-video

Been trying to get local videos playing on an Android (4.4.2) device using Ionic.

The closest I can get is:

```
<video controls poster="img/video-stills/video.png">
    <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

This shows the poster image, shows the controls and a play butt and then when clicking play it crashes the app.

I have tried every combination of type / video type etc but cannot get this working.

Any ideas? The videos are located in www/videos and have tried appending the android_assets link etc.